# Firebase Auth JS signInWithCustomToken hangs

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Ionic+Capacitor to build an app, and in the iOS WebView, this line hangs:

```js
const userCredential = await signInWithCustomToken(auth, token.data.result);
```

I see on my Firebase console that the user is created when I make the call, so I know it has the intended effect, and I've wrapped it in a try/catch in case it's throwing, but the error bloc never gets called & the function hangs indefinitely. Has anyone else run into issues with this function hanging? Is there a known workaround? Thanks!

Comment: Specifically, after putting debug logs in the firebase lib, it looks like it's the following call that's hanging: `/v1/accounts:lookup`, which would explain why the registration succeeds. Still no idea why the hang is happening.

Comment: Another interesting tidbit is that this flow works fine from the iOS SDK - it's only hanging in JS in a Capacitor app.

Comment: Found a quick fix! Downgrading to `8.10.1` and using the v8 sdk does the trick, no more hang!